# How to group similar Laravel routes using the same controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I want to *pretty-up* my routes, ie, I have such entries:

```
// DataTable
Route::get('dt/reservations/{room_id]', 'DataTablesController@reservations')->where(['room_id', '[0-9]+']);
Route::get('dt/rooms/{area_id]', 'DataTablesController@rooms')->where(['area_id', '[0-9]+']);
Route::get('dt/departments', 'DataTablesController@departments');
Route::get('dt/addresses', 'DataTablesController@areas');
Route::get('dt/areas', 'DataTablesController@areas');
```

I would like to make it more understandable. I can add prefix what would give me:

```
// DataTable
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dt'], function () {
    Route::get('reservations/{room_id]', 'DataTablesController@reservations')->where(['room_id', '[0-9]+']);
    Route::get('rooms/{area_id]', 'DataTablesController@rooms')->where(['area_id', '[0-9]+']);
    Route::get('departments', 'DataTablesController@departments');
    Route::get('addresses', 'DataTablesController@areas');
    Route::get('areas', 'DataTablesController@areas');
});
```

But can I somehow make the rest too? The route name and method name will always be the same.
Is it possible to make something like:

```
// DataTable
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dt'], function () {
    Controller => DataTablesController,
    Methods => [
        'reservations',
        'rooms',
        'departments',
        'addresses',
        'areas'
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Although a very good feature. But it can't be done in Laravel**

> All your routes must be explicit, `Laravel` won't/can't assume that you
>   are using same controller for all the routes.
>   So you will have to define all the routes explicitly.

***Only Resource Controllers can have implicit routing in Laravel***

Take a look here....

[Route use the same controller](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/route-use-the-same-controller-in-laravel-52?page=1)

Comment: Too bad, tag me, if this changes :)

Comment: @DainisAbols sure, will let you know :)

Comment: @ManishYadav You didn't let him know... [news about it](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-8-80-0), [simple tutorial doing it](https://programmingfields.com/how-to-use-group-routes-for-the-same-controller-in-laravel-9/)

Comment: Thanks for the update. @Poen please have a look if you still are looking for a solution